# Change a tree root

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, tree

I am trying to write an algorithm to change a tree root.
Tree is represented as an array: `['A', ['B', ['D']], ['C']]`.

I wrote some algorithm that uses recursion but it doesn't work correctly for all test cases that I wrote. Can't find a mistake. Also maybe someone remember examples how to solve that.

My code:

```
   const change_root_ = (node: Tree, target: string, prevNode: Tree): Tree => {
      if (!node) {
        return node;
      }

      const nodeLabel = node[0];

      if (nodeLabel === target) {
        return [
          ...node,
          prevNode
        ];
      }

      const leftNode = node[1];
      if (leftNode) {
        return change_root_(
          leftNode,
          target,
          [...node.slice(0, 1), ...node.slice(2)]
        );
      }

      const rightNode = node[2];
      return change_root_(rightNode, target, [...node.slice(0, 2)]);
    }

    const change_root = (tree: Tree, newRootLabel: string): Tree => {
      return change_root_(tree, newRootLabel);
    };
```

Here you can see the actual code + test cases at the bottom. http://jsbin.com/noyeponove/edit?js,console,output

Comment: This seems to be similar to rotation of a tree until the given node becomes the new root.

Comment: Your algorithm only traverses the tree down to a specific direction, regardless of where the new root node is actually located. It also forgets `prevNode` whenever it goes down, which is nonsense because then `change_root_` would be unable to return the whole original tree. I think you need a clear contract for the function and its arguments in the first place, [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) should help.